# What logs can I search to find out which processes used 'nice'?

Tags: linux, logs, nice

I had a huge spike, in a plesk server, which brought it down due IO blocking.  I see in the Plesk graphs there was a large increase in `nice`.  I think thats normally cron jobs, im thinking also maybe a mail queue, as well as any program that uses `niceness` im guessing.

Is there a certain technique that i can use to trace what `nice` commands were running that day?  Which logs might I check on, or what method might I use for this?

Edit:
I did notice I can get clues, by looking in `htop` (or `top`) you can clearly see which processes use `nice` during runtime at least.